# Giving a user the choice to appear offline in a view showing online users

Tags: views

I created a views block which displays users which are online. I would like to give a user a choice to be able to appear offline (i.e not be listed in the block) when he/she is online.

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Drupal 7, you can go to `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`, attach a Boolean field to user accounts to allow the user to select their preference, then filter on that user field in your view to exclude those who opt out.

Comment: Please, do you know if there is a way using views, to make the Boolean field appear as an attachment to the original block? In this way users can choose to appear offline without going to there user account page. Thanks.

Comment: This is another good question. Please post it as a separate question.

Comment: Okay, will do so.